# Ext4.2.1 How to open a new browser tab with widget inside from another browser tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, widget, ext4, browser-tab

How can I open a widget in a new browser tab like `window.open()` from `Ext4.2.1` application. I need to be able to open widget in a new browser tab similar to what 'maximize' tool does but for the whole thing to open in a new tab window.My best guess so far is to open a prepared .aspx page like  window.open(url) and somehow to pass the widget to the window. But the tricky
part is to pass the widget , there can be many widget to pass ,so I can't just hardcode the widget on the page.
Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: For clarification, are you looking to open a new `tab` within a `tabpanel`? Would you be able to provide some of the code you have so far?

Comment: I am trying to open a complete new window.Tab means browser tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext based applications starts with main Ext.container.Viewport inside Ext.app.Application.
The solution is to question the state of the application before the main Viewport is built.
For example in my case I question the URL params . If in the params there is some param - in my case 'widget' I know that I need to build a single widget based on widget name from URL param (?widget='somewidgetalias'). I then create the widget by alias  and a single widget viewport(regular viewport with no items) and I pass this created widget as item.

```
 Ext.create('NG.view.WidgetViewport', { 
            items: [{
                xtype: widgetName
            }]
        });
```

If I don't see the param in the URL , I continue to create a regular general viewport that creates the application.
From the main application I open a new window with javascript like this :
window.open(url, '_blank', specs);, the URL is the URL of the application and the param of widget='somewidgetalias' .